# How to implement scopeButtonTitles for a customized UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a customized UISearchBar, when an user click on the searchBar, I want to show an additional buttons. So, I'm using scopeButtonTitles property to display the additional buttons. But, it's not appearing on the UISearchBar.

```
customSearchController = CustomSearchController(searchResultsController: self, searchBarFrame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 50.0), searchBarFont:  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0),                                                             searchBarTextColor: UIColor.white, searchBarTintColor: UIColor.primaryBlue())
customSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
customSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
customSearchController.customSearchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("Search", comment: "Search")
customSearchController.customSearchBar.accessibilityLabel = customSearchController.searchBar.placeholder
//Scope Buttons
customSearchController.customSearchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [NSLocalizedString("List", comment: "List"), NSLocalizedString("Map", comment: "Map")]
```

If I'm not using customize UISearchBar, it's working fine. the actual problem is when I'm going for customize UISearchBar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [`showsScopeBar`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchbar/1624319-showsscopebar) property of `UISearchBar` to `true` to the show the scopeBar.

```
customSearchController.customSearchBar.showsScopeBar = true
```

**Edit:** For that you can use delegate method `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` and show the scopebar.

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    customSearchController.customSearchBar.showsScopeBar = true
    //set the frame so it will show scope bar properly.
}
```

Now if you want to hide the scoprBar after search then you can use `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` to hide the scope bar.

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    customSearchController.customSearchBar.showsScopeBar = false
    //set the frame again
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your approach, it's working. But it's overlapping with the UISearchBar and also, it appearing initially. Actually, I want to display an additional buttons, only after an user click on the search button. Also, I'm hardcoding the value of UISearchBar CGRect.

Comment: @PradeshV Welcome mate :)

Comment: For iOS 13+ `searchController.automaticallyShowsScopeBar = true` and this fixes Catalyst issues too.